# hover effect over nav. li but exclude the rest of the li elements

Tags: html, css, hover, html-lists

```css
.nav li:hover a{
background-color: darkgrey;
}

.navbar li {
list-style-type: none;

float: right;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin-top: 17px;
font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
font-weight: lighter;
```

```html
    <body>
        <nav class="navbar">

            <ul>
                <li><a class="list" href="./test.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="#"> Service</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="#"> Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="./test.html"> Training</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Hey guy's.

In the nav bar i gave the li elements a hover effect.
now is the problem that it automatically applies to all the li on the page.
i want the effect only in my nav. bar but how ever i try it is or to all the  on the page or none.
the code how it is in the snippet doesnt work neither the only way how i can make the list hover is by:
li:hover a{background-color: darkgrey;} but then obviously it applies the all the li on the page.
is there a way around this?
thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
a.list:hover {
  background-color: darkgrey;
}

.navbar li {
list-style-type: none;

float: right;
padding-left: 5px;
padding-right: 5px;
margin-top: 17px;
font-family: myriad-pro, sans-serif;
font-weight: lighter;
```

```html
<body>
        <nav class="navbar">

            <ul>
                <li><a class="list" href="./test.html"> Home</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="#"> Service</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="#"> Contact</a></li>
                <li><a class="list" href="./test.html"> Training</a></li>
            </ul>
```

wrong logic for the CSS. To have a hover effect you need:

```css
a.(class/id):hover {
  style
}
```

However, I'm also not sure if that list is actually a good idea to do this. This will end in creating bad and ineffective habits.
After your Nav-Link has been visited the color will turn so might consider:

```css
a.link:link {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #141414; 
}

a.link:visited {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #141414; 
}

a.link:active {
    text-decoration: underline;
    color: #141414; 
}
```

This will prevent that a link button text going to change the color an unwanted way.